# How to change the name of uploaded file /Android + PHP

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to figure out how can i change the name of a file i'm about to upload.

I really prefer to changed it's name before i upload it to the server

This is the upload method at client(Android) side -

```
   private void doFileUpload(){

    File file1 = new File(pathofFile);


    String urlString = "http://12.8.1.10/uploads/upload_media_test.php";



    try
    {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
         FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
         FileBody bin2 = new FileBody(file2);
         MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
         reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin1);
         reqEntity.addPart("user", new StringBody("User"));
         post.setEntity(reqEntity);
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
         resEntity = response.getEntity();
         final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
         if (resEntity != null) {
             Log.i("RESPONSE",response_str);
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                         try {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload Complete. Check the server uploads directory.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                       }
                });
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
         Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
  }
```

If it's possible to do it at the client side - please try to be specific as you can about how to do so.

If it's not possible, and the only option is to do that at the server side,
so i adding the php code - so you could explain me what i need to change there, thanks

Php code -

```
    $target_path1 = "uploads/";

$target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile1']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
    echo "The first file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']).
    " has been uploaded.";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path1;
}
```

Comment: So are you just copy pasting some code without any knowledge how it works?

Comment: no when it's coming to php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the target path you can change the name here,

```
 $fileName = $_FILES["uploadedfile1"]["name"];
 $ext = "." . end(explode(".", $fileName));
 $target_path1 = "uploads/";

 $target_path1 = $target_path1 . $name_of_file_here . $ext;
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile1']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
  echo "The first file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name'])." has been uploaded.";
//rest of code here....
```

Also as a side note, if you want your file name to come from your android, you will have to send additional post data with the name you wish and set `$name_of_file_here` to that variable.
The `$target_path1` should read similarly to "*uploads/myPic.jpg*"

Comment: correct me if im wrong but if i change the name of the file as you said so - does it still knows what the extension of the file is? seem like it change it to the name but without let's say '.jpg.

Comment: append the extension of the file with `."jpg"`

Comment: so is this he right way to write it in on - $target_path1 = $target_path1 . $name_of_file_here . "jpg";

Comment: edited my post, added more flexible extension appending

Comment: I guess i need to swith the $name with $fileName at the 2ed line. but also the result im getting is - newnamejpg - there's no dot

Comment: edited, of course I was writing from my head really my mistake.